# Внедрение xlsx файла в андроид

Tags: android, xlsx

Имеется файл `xlsx`, в нем есть список пользователей.
1. Как реализовать фильтр пользователей по критерии?
2. Как вообще внедрить `xlsx` в андроид и считывать оттуда данные?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно внедрить именно xlsx, а не просто данные из него?

Comment: ну я и имел виду данные из его.

Comment: Так а данные вы один раз достали и сконвертировали в любой вам понятный формат, да даже просто массив/вектор. Или это все еще не очень просто?

Comment: я новичок ,и много пока не знаю, но в моем приложении ,есть файл который я создал в xlsx формате  и он заполнен так:фамилия дата рождения рост и т.д. и как мне получить в мое приложение эти данные из xlsx формата?

Answer (score 0):

Ну насчёт внедрения, вы можете положить ваш файлик в папку assets например, и считывать из него данные с помощью библиотеки Apache POI. Другое дело в том, что с этим есть некоторые проблемы,и  это будет немного мудрёно для новичка. Я советую вам просто взять данные из xlsx-файла и перенести их в текстовый файл, а лучше в базу данных, и считывать её в приложении. Это будет полезнее и проще для новичка, чем возиться с xlsx.